# Python (Tkinter) - canvas for-loop color change

Tags: python, for-loop, canvas, tkinter

I generated a grid using a for-loop in Tkinter, but want to know how I would be able to bind an on-click function to  such that when I click on each individual generated rectangle, the rectangle will change color.

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def rowgen(row, col):
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            w.create_rectangle(25+50*i, 25+50*j, 50+50*i, 50+50*j, fill="green")

w = Canvas(master, width=225, height=225)
w.pack()
rowgen(4, 4)


master.resizable(0,0)
mainloop()
```

I'm thinking that I have to first iterate through another for-loop to make an event, where if I click within these coordinates, I'd reconfig the color of one of the rectangles.

Comment: The following link is to a tutorial on how to register a click.  Is uses text but substitute rectangles and it will function the same way http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0360__Tkinker/Canvasclickevent.htm

Answer (score 0):

By following Curly Joe's hints and making some mistakes, I got the following, which requires only one tag_bind.  You might want to try it yourself first.

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def box_click(event):
    box = event.widget.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
    print(box)  # remove later
    w.itemconfig(box, fill='red')

def rowgen(row, col):
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            w.create_rectangle(25+50*i, 25+50*j, 50+50*i, 50+50*j,
                               fill="green", tag='BOX')

w = Canvas(master, width=225, height=225)
w.pack()
rowgen(4, 4)
w.tag_bind('BOX', '<Button-1>', box_click)

master.resizable(0,0)
mainloop()
```